# Need to run @BeforeSuite when debugging TestNG in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng

I am trying to debug a TestNG test in IntelliJ that is part of a test automation suite. However, before this test can run, I need to run the code contained in the method marked @BeforeSuite.

How can I configure IntelliJ to run the code in @BeforeSuite automatically when debugging a test?

Answer (score 0):

If the method marked @BeforeSuite is in the same class then it will be automatically run first prior to your @Test methods. You just need to keep the debug point in @BeforeSuite method.

Answer (score 0):

Work around:

I found that I could specify to debug all tests in a "group". I can tag my @BeforeSuite class and my method under test with a group of "Debug".

Then In the Intellij run configuration, I tell it to run the "Debug" group.

Voila.